# Whats wrong with my code, while accessing SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm following a tutorial on android SQLiteDatabase for android and when here press the count button it work however for me it dosen't. I have add some try methon to see what going on but it still doesn't work. here my code:

```
public class MyDatabasaDemo extends Activity {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "JADB.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "myTable";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table"+ DATABASE_TABLE;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button butCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButCreate);
        Button butAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButAdd);
        Button butCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButCount);
        Button butShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButShow);

        butCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SQLiteDatabase myDB;
                try{
                myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                myDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                myDB.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Creat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }catch(SQLException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }
            }

        });

        butAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SQLiteDatabase myDB;

                myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

                ContentValues newRow = new ContentValues();
                newRow.put("col1", "ok");
                myDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, newRow);

                myDB.close();


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "row added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });


        butCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SQLiteDatabase myDB;

                myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

                String[] resultColumns = new String[]{"_id","col1"};

        Cursor allRows = myDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, resultColumns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                myDB.close();

                Integer c = allRows.getCount();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "count: "+c.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }
```

the database is create but the toast message inside the frist button dosen't work so I wondering if it's not closing.

thankyou

Comment: @user583713 - can you remove the code that isn't relavant - I'm not sure which button click listener you're talking about.

Comment: The create table statement does not look correct, it misses a space between table keyword and table name.

Comment: You should log the exception message to get more information about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to create a table with no columns, then inserting a record.  You should change your database creation sql:

```
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "col1";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" ("+
    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
    COLUMN_NAME +" text not null"
    +");";
```